# How do I remove and repair the hex file on my Ds2250t-32-16 micro controller

Tags: embedded, reverse-engineering, microcontroller, firmware, 8051

Hi I have a circuit board that runs my on board water maker the chip [Ds2250t-32-16](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DS2250T-32-16%2B/DS2250T-32-16%2B-ND/1197381) is faulty. The manufacturer won't supply the chip or the hex file . They want me to upgrade to a new board cost $3k Aud. I can but the chip for $50 online and a kit to load it from Dallas Microprocessor. My question is can I download the current file and repair it from the chip . I can get hold of 7 different chips all faulty but with different faults . Could these be overlaid on each other to build a correct file. Any help or advice would be appreciated . If I was working I would just pay for a new one but being retired 3k is a lot of cash. 
Mike

Comment: Can you tell us more about what the fault is?  How do you know this particular chip is faulty?  What about the other 6 of them you say are also faulty--the same questions apply to those ones.  I assume this is for a private yacht?  It appears the module has batteries on board--have you tried replacing them already?

Comment: I found an application note here: http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN595.pdf which says "Once locked, the code can be erased, but not extracted."  Presumably the chip you have is locked, which may make it very difficult to extract the code you need.  This seems like the key to your entire question (hence I added the reverse-engineering tag, among others).  What make and model of water maker is this?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replies . Yes it's a private yacht the water maker is a sea recovery aqua whisper. The local dealer has tested it and tells me it's the micro processor same as 7 others he has in a drawer .Sea Recovery don't seem to want to give him or me the file so I was trying to find a way to get around it without spending lots of my living money.the fault on mine is it won't power up at all the others have differing faults some won't read the salt monitor or the clock has gone etc. ahhh the batteries yes it does have them I could try and replace it. The boat was struck by lightning

Comment: Thanks John yes reveres engineering would work I thought if we could extract the files. Lay them over each other and see which bits are faulty. I. Will keep trying with Sea Recovery as well.its quite a nuisance knowing a $50 part is holding us up and the hex file could be emailed to us if they wanted to.

Comment: I doubt that re-loading the code will fix it, rather there is probably a damaged bit of hardware.  The board contains several basic components, including a battery or two and some capacitors.  I'd remove these and test them, in order: batteries, capacitors, and then the other surface-mount components.  This way you can leave the microprocessor intact.  You could even desolder the microprocessor from your board and transplant it onto a new board, if you believe the microprocessor is OK (maybe at least one of the 7 is!).  I doubt the code itself is "scrambled", hopefully the main chip is OK.

Comment: The chip may be $50, but what the $3K gets you is are the rights to use (but not steal) someone else's intellectual property.  Software isn't free.  What is an "on board water maker" in any case!?  It seems to me that this question is not about software development, so not appropriate to SO.  It seems very unlikely that the fault is in the software - flash memory is pretty robust.  More likely that he part has been subject to ESD.

Comment: @Clifford: a water maker takes seawater and electricity and produces drinking water.  It's fairly popular on cruising yachts (which we already established the OP has).  You're right that software is not free, but the OP paid for the device and has the right to use it; a lightning strike does not take that right away.  It hardly matters though, since downloading the code from the finished product is probably neither viable nor efficacious, as I think we both agree.

Comment: @JohnZwinck : Of course I figured out what a "water maker" was (apart from a misnomer - desalinator perhaps?), my point was that the term is in the application domain and deserved clarification in this context. Lightning strike is hardly the major or most likely cause of ESD damage - simply touching the board is the most likely cause; and failure can occur long after the actual discharge that caused it, which is why so many people (including engineers who should know better) seem to think it is a myth - you have to wonder why he has so many damaged boards!?